# How to maintain a websocket open until proper closure?

Tags: tomcat, websocket

I'm studying websocket and I tried the tomcat howto.[here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/web-socket-howto.html)
Everything is clear except the fact that after 15 seconds of inactivity the server call the onclose method with status 1002 ( it should be protocol error).  What should I do to maintain the websocket open until i want to close it? Am I missing something?
Ps: I'm using Tomcat 7.0.27

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue and stopped it by setting the connectionTimeout higher in the server.xml config.

J

Answer (score 0):

You may need to override getReadTimeout method, which is used to set socket timeout in milliseconds. returning -1 ensures that websocket is always open until proper closure from the client side.

```
@Override
public int getReadTimeout() {
    return -1;
}
```